# How can you stop html and javascript from being entered into text boxes on your site?

Tags: javascript, html, security, textbox

I've been freelance working on the development of a web app for a company, and I realised that in any of the textboxes you can just type html tags or lines of javascript, which is obviously very problematic as I don't want the users to be able to do things that mess how it looks or functions. Is there a way of making sure html/javascript can't be written into text boxes?

Comment: What are the textboxes for? Data to be sent to the server or client-side functionality?

Comment: both, for instance I have a database table called Website with dynamodb, you type in the website name, the website url, additional details such as google analytics related things, and then click save. It sends that to the database (I have regex checking all of the fields are as they should be) and then the page reloads and pulls that new site from the database into a new tab. The problem is you can just type html straight off the bat before sending it to the database and it will change the layout/functioning of the page.

Comment: Typing into a textbox changes the layout of the site without hitting any submit?

Comment: @Starscream1984 that's correct

Comment: so there's some kind of keypress or onblur event which is taking that textbox data and doing something with it before submission - you could place some validation in the event handler, like your regex checking, and discard the data if it doesn't match.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to assume that all data being POSTed, or sent via the URI to the server is malicious, until you check explicitly that it is not (Perl actually has a taint mode to enforce this), and validate the data received is valid for the data type you're expecting. You shouldn't rely on validation (only) on the client, as a malicious user may craft special requests without actually using your front end.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that I dont have a lot of info for the problem I will give a try, so be nice to me!! (please provide some more info)

Html or Javascript they have some common expressions, you can exclude those from the textfields by writing a custom javascript validator.

Comment: Actually @RowlandShaw answer is a more complete one. As far as the js validation, you will include it into a js file and link it to your application using html.

Answer (score 1):

You should validate any user input (textboxes, etc.). This means in example that if you are asking for a number, then you check that the user input is a number, and reject anything else.

You can't (and you should not) "forbid to write HTML/JavaScript", you **must**  "check that the input is valid against what you are expecting".

You should validate the input as soon as you want to use it. If you have some sort of `input`, `keypress`, `keyup` or similar event handler, you should validate the data before using it.

Also you should not inject user data as HTML. In example, don't use `element.innerHTML = data;` but instead use `element.textContent = data;` so the data are not parsed as HTML but just injected as text. (if you are using jQuery, use `$(...).text(data)` instead of `$(...).html(data)`.

Comment: I have regex to ensure that the user input is what it should be, but you can still type html tags into the textbox. The page will throw an error, saying that the input is invalid, but by the time that happens the html has been typed and has affected the page in some way, do you know what I mean?

Comment: How could typing text in a textbox affecting the page? What are you doing with the data? Are you validating the data before using it? Are you validating while the user inputs or after he finished? Please provide more info.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear - basically imagine a set of tabs with previously made sites, and you are on the page to create a new site. As you type the site name, the tab updates with the text you are writing.